# Low impedance as GND and current measurement, applied voltage sharing the same lead

Tags: amplifier, ground, current-measurement, input-impedance

(Image 1 is for the general idea, image 2 is for questions 1 and 2, image 3 is for the 3rd question)

In the setup shown below, the tuning fork is driven by an AC voltage source being connected to one prong and its current output is measured by a current amplifier connected to the other prong.

I looked up the specifications of a current amplifier such as [this](https://www.zhinst.com/products/hf2ta#specifications).  It says

> input impedance (DC, Z // 15 pF)  50 Ω - 70 kΩ.

So my question is the following:

1. If the input impedance of the current amplifier is low enough, can we basically treat it like GND and just not connect the ground side of the AC voltage? This would allow me to connect one prong of the fork to the AC voltage source via one cable
2. I am not sure how to read the spec of the input impedance.  Is it saying 50 Ω for DC and 70 kΩ under different conditions?
3. This diagram shows the tuning fork electrically excited with each of the two wires connected to either of the prongs (one wire, one prong). Then, there are cables from preamplifier to the tuning fork (again one wire, one prong).  I am not sure how this configuration would work.  Wouldn't current be split and hence the output of the current amplifier will not give you the accurate reading?

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

Comment: Do you just want to understand why/how it works? or what?  ..... 50 Ohm driver and 75k||15pF  preamp.  Is this for Non-contact-atomic force microscopy (ncAFM)

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist  I apologize for laying out my questions in a confusing way.  Question 1. In the second image, they are basically treating V- of the preamp as GND, which allows them to apply AC voltage across the tuning fork by connecting one prong to the voltage source using one cable. How valid is this? (I understand V+ and V- are basically at the same voltage but V+ is grounded whereas V- is not) Is this acceptable?   2. when you are given something such as "input impedance (DC, Z // 15 pF) : 50 Ω - 70 kΩ,"  how would you make sense of 50 Ω - 70 kΩ?

Comment: 50 out 70k in.  ....

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Is it 50Ω for output impedance because of impedance matching?

Comment: Yes, so changing ground paths could alter that

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that would work. But an Opamp based transimpedance amplifier will not have a well defined input impedance to work correctly at the frequencies of a tuning fork crystal resonator. Not only do you have a parallel capacitance, but also a frequency dependent component that comes from the feedback of the opamp. But the phase shift of the opamp's response depends on the beta of the input transistors (I assume you are using a bipolar opamp), which in turn depends on temperature. I.e. if you get the system working, it will wobble around with each waft of air that shifts the temperature of the opamp by a degree up or down. Instead you should use a transistor (e.g. BC848) in common-base configuration to give the resonator a stable foothold. From the transistor you can then do all the processing you need and it will be (mostly) isolated from the resonator.
2. At DC you have 70k impedance, with a 2pF parallel capacitor to GND. Note that you cannot generalize this impedance to other frequencies readily, without knowing the transfer characteristics of the opamp. You will either need to get the data for the frequency you are working at from the manufacturer or you have to measure it yourself.
3. It looks like that the excitation voltage is connected through the pre-amp. So it's likely the same circuit as 2.